# Заблокировать root в Linaro Linux

Tags: linux, debian

Имею образ Linaro под ARM.
Там есть проблема: при запуске всегда запускается консоль с root и происходит автологин даже если пароль стоит.
Я создал другого пользователя и попробовал заблокировать рут командой `sudo passwd -l root`, но всё равно при каждом запуске происходит автологин.

Где этот автологин может быть прописан?
И как его можно убрать и полностью отключить root?

Comment: если там не `systemd`, то скорей всего в `/etc/inittab`

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/783560/454489

Comment: /etc/initab отсутствует. И я так понимаю, что в этом образе именно systemd. А не подскажите, как это можно автологин в systemd?  
Я нашёл лишь такое:  
 
```systemctl stop serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service && systemctl disable serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service && rm /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty\@tty1.service```  
 
Но оно не отключает автологин.